# Cannot center my menu option items

Tags: javascript, html, css, drop-down-menu, centering

I'm having trouble centering the items **within** my dropdown menu.
I've tried many things suggested on this website and none seem to work.

Here is my CSS:

```
select {

    -webkit-appearance: button;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -webkit-padding-start: 6px;
    -webkit-padding-end: 6px;
    background-color: #050505;
    color: #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid #ffffff;
    box-shadow: 11px 10px 5px #000000;
    text-shadow:4px 4px 10px #000000;
    font-family: "UglyQua", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-top: 2px;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

..and my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function jump(form) {
var myindex=form.menu.selectedIndex
if (form.menu.options[myindex].value != "0") 
{
window.open(form.menu.options[myindex].value, 
target="iframe1");
}
}
//-->
</script>
</head>

<center>
<body>

<form name="lissamenu2" ACTION=URI>
<select name="menu" onchange="jump(this.form)">

<option value="0" selected>Select site:</option>   
<option value="http://www.google.com/">Google</option>
<option value="http://www.youtube.com/">YouTube</option>
<option value="http://www.stackoverflow.com/">StackOverflow</option>

</select>
</form>

</center>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SELECT`/`OPTION` cannot accept the same styling at regular HTML elements since these are more closely-tied to the OS. You'll notice a `SELECT` will look differently on a Mac and a PC. If you want more control you're best to use a JavaScript-based replacement.

See: http://www.jankoatwarpspeed.com/reinventing-a-drop-down-with-css-and-jquery/

Comment: There are jQuery plug-ins that will take standard selects and turn them into script-based menus.